# understanding mongodb structure from a mysql background

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, nosql

coming from a relational db (mySql) background, i used to have multiple tables with relational key to store data. I never knew noSql such as mongodb but wanted to deploy it for the next project, but still grasping with the structure model which are alien to me.

Let say i want to build a marketplace where there's Users, Items & Items category inside different mySql tables:

- User table : UserID, Name, etc
- Items : ItemID, Owner(UserID), Category(CatID), etc
- Items Category : CatID, ItemName

Correct me if i'm wrong, what i would do in mongodb is create json userdata first and then inject items within each record

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("51f7be1cd6189a56c399d456"),
"name" : "john",
"age" : 31,
"email":"foo@bar.io",
"items" : [
  {"item name":"corolla",
  "item category":"car" },
  {"item name":"vespa",
  "item category":"bike" }, an so on.....
]}
```

so i only have 1 dataset which is user that contain everything that the user have. i wont have items or categories tables. no more item_id or cat_id because it is identified with item name, so when i want to search particular item, i would search it with names.

CMIIW that would create a very huge record if the user have many items. If that's the norm, how many characters one record could store? Would it be less efficient for the server to grab a huge chunk at one time, and then parse it to my query?

or will it make more sense to have 2 datasets, one is users and the other is items so it would make a smaller object records pieces.

Answer (score 0):

An important thing to know is how the application is going to interact with the data.

Data in MongoDB has a flexible schema. A great thing about this is that it allows you to focus on your application design and let the database design conform for the benefit of the application (See [Domain Driven Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) approach). Instead of designing your database schema first, you should figure out how the application will access the data.

I would recommend to checkout [MongoDB: Data Modelling Introduction](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/). The key consideration for the structure of your documents is the decision to embed or to use references.

When designing data models, always consider the application usage of the data (i.e. queries, updates, and processing of the data) as well as the inherent structure of the data itself.

See [Operational Factors and Data Models](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-operations/) for factors to consider with each models. One of them is what you've mentioned - the size of a document. The limit for a BSON document size at the moment is [16MB](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size). Also see [Document Growth](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-operations/#document-growth) for size related factor to consider.

In terms of saving data transfer of from the server, you could [limit fields to return from a query](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#limit-fields-to-return-from-a-query).

Hope that helps.